# Carousel in mobile development

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, sencha-architect

We’ve created an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 (Beta) web site with Visual Studio 2010. The web site will be used (or viewed) by standard browsers and by mobile devices.

Because of this, we’ve decided to use the new .mobile.cshtml pages offered in MVC 4.0. We basically copy/pasted all the Views and renamed them accordingly (with .mobile in them).
We are now ready to begin playing around the .mobile views…

Considering I have no past experience in mobile development, I’m curious to find out a few things. As an example, I’m trying to create a simple carousel that will gently slide and once it reaches the last image, it will start again at the first one.

I’m grasping at straws to find a simple example and in addition, I keep seeing/reading about Sencha Architect (which I’ve decided to download, only to realize it is some sort of IDE to develop mobile apps…correct me if I’m wrong).

In order to properly start, can anyone explain (or clarify) the differences between why should I use something like Sencha Architect versus using Visual Studio with jQuery Mobile?

Thanks.

Comment: For your carousel, try SwipeJS, it uses 1:1 movement so it feels kinda like you're moving the element with your finger: http://swipejs.com/

Comment: Wow that is indeed a nice example :-) Many thanks Jasper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed correct with sencha architect. Like Yourself I was puzzeled but it is designed to work alongside rather than with visual studio which I really have a hard time understanding 
Due to senchas unique way in which it creates 
Interface components.  This doesn't mean you can't use sencha touch with mvc though in the same manner as jquery mobile.  You can write your pages in mvc much the same way as you do now and use the applyto method in sencha to attach the sencha widget to it

As for the argument of sencha touch vs jquery mobile its down to you I guess